# Get Address in Russian Language using Android Geocoder getFromLocation

Tags: java, android, dictionary

I am using GeoCoder to fetch address from lat and long. here is my code:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

It gives me address properly, but in English. I need the address in Russian language. What i have tried so far is to set locale to Russian language and pass it to geocoder object.

```
Locale aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("RU").setScript("Latn").setRegion("RS").build();
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, aLocale);
List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

But still i get address in English instead of Russian. Please suggest what should I do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
        Locale aLocale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("RU").setScript("Latn").setRegion("RS").build();
        } else {
            aLocale = new Locale("RU");
        }
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, aLocale);
        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```

Comment: still get latin not russian cyrillic

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale aLocale;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            aLocale = new Locale.Builder().setLanguage("RU").setScript("Cyrl").setRegion("RS").build();
        } else {
            aLocale = new Locale("RU");
        }
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, aLocale);
        List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
```